# simultaneous rendering from cameras in geonode instances?

Tags: camera, geometry-nodes, instances

Is there a way to access each camera instanced on a geometry node and render from each of them? I created a geometry node shape and was able to instance cameras on it, but I am unable to neither access camera instances nor set them as the active camera. I am aware that if we had multiple cameras, we could run some script to render each of them for each frame. But since it is a geonode setup, the camera's functionality is limited.
Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: i wish this would be possible, but AFAIK with the current status of GN this isn't possible. Maybe with help of python...

Comment: thanks for the reply it would have been really neat if we could do that, but it makes more sense for the geometry nodes not to support camera-related systems.